# Why is this Dropdown failing in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, development-environment

Here is the code in my build method

```
Column(
                    children: [
                      DropdownButton<String>(
                          value: dropdownvalue,
                          items: <String>['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
                              .map((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              dropdownvalue = newValue!;
                            });
                          }),
                      DropdownButton<String>(
                          value: dropdownvalue,
                          items: <String>['E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
                              .map((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              dropdownvalue = newValue!;
                            });
                          }),
                    ],
                  )
```

I have  String dropdownvalue = '--'; in my State class

The error I get is:

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: --.
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 894 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
```

I'm just trying to have multiple independent drop downs on my screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should have a value per dropdown in order to store the selected value for each, instead of one for all of them. So you should have a **dropdownvalue1** for the first dropdown, **dropdownvalue2** for the second, etc. Also the default values on your dropdownvalue properties should be among the ones in the list of values fed to each dropdown, therefore you should implement it as follows:

```dart
  String dropdownvalue1 = '--';
  String dropdownvalue2 = '--';
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: [
          DropdownButton<String>(
              value: dropdownvalue1,
              items: <String>['--','A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
                  .map((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  dropdownvalue1 = newValue!;
                });
              }),
          DropdownButton<String>(
              value: dropdownvalue2,
              items: <String>['--','E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
                  .map((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  dropdownvalue2 = newValue!;
                });
              }),
        ],
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. Same error

Comment: Interesting. Here's the code as a Gist (https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/587328e1b484dba6ab2e18e781bb8b7a). Can you run it on DartPad.dev and check out what I mean? Let me know if that helps.